# Updating PC hardware caused Windows to BSOD on booting

Tags: windows-7

I recently upgraded to an AMD Phenom II X6 1055T processor, an ASUS M5A99XEVO mobo and 8 Gb of hyperX modules, upon booting up the PC and loading Windows results in a BSOD.

I have no idea what the error says as it flashes too fast for me to look at it, I previously had an Intel C2D e6750 CPu, a MSI 945G mobo board and 2Gb of RAM, what could have caused the BSOD?

The new motherboard uses UEFI could that be the cause for the BSOD?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Windows selects proper chipset/ACPI drivers during installation, and they can't be changed later. You have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: I see, but i previously was running a P4, 845 mobo and 1.5 ddr1 (yeah on W7) and then upgraded to the C2D, and had no problems with it? it booted fine.

Comment: Changing motherboards on a windows rig without reinstalling is a bit of a lottery. Regardless of whether it boots, it's best to reinstall the OS.

Comment: it is not necessary all cases  install windows in update windows mode will also save all the settings and will let the windows to run fine.. some cases data backup matters..

Answer (score 1):

You have already mention that you have upgraded from Intel C2D to AMD processor. Both of these board have different ChipSet and Processing architecture.

> In Simple words the drivers your new motherboard will almost certainly
>   have different chipset(s) than the one it is replacing, especially if
>   it has an onboard video chip that provides the video instead of a
>   dedicated graphics card, and which has its own chipset.  If windows
>   does not find drivers for new hardware drivers then it will cause such error.

Check this "[Motherboard upgrade or replacement: How can I replace the motherboard in my PC without having to reinstall Windows XP/Windows Vista/Windows 7?](http://www.pcbuyerbeware.co.uk/MotherboardProblems.htm#replace)"

It may help you understand the reason and let you solve the problem..